# Копировать на другой лист наименования товаров и их остатки

Tags: excel, vba

Макрос, приведённый ниже, переносит на новый лист разницу между двумя значениями, расположенными в одном листе на столбцах B и C. Если разность меньше либо равна нулю, то вывод не осуществляется.

```
Sub ResultBC()
Dim a()
Dim dRes As Long
Dim i As Long, k As Long
    a = Range("B2:C6").Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(a)
        dRes = a(i, 2) - a(i, 1)

        If dRes > 0 Then
            k = k + 1: a(k, 1) = dRes
        End If
    Next i

    Worksheets("Result").Range("B2").Resize(k, 1).Value = a
End Sub
```

Требуется подправить макрос так, чтобы на новый лист также попадали ячейки столбца A, которые расположены на строках, разность которых переносится на новый лист.

Вывод должен осуществляться в отсортированном виде (наибольшие значения и названия товаров должны быть наверху листа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub ResultBC()
    Dim a()
    Dim dRes As Long
    Dim i As Long, k As Long

    a = Range("A2:C6").Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(a)
        dRes = a(i, 3) - a(i, 2)

        If dRes > 0 Then
            k = k + 1
            a(k, 1) = a(i, 1)
            a(k, 2) = dRes
        End If
    Next i

    If k > 0 Then
        Worksheets("Result").Range("A2").Resize(k, 2).Value = a
k = 15
        Call sort_(k)
    End If
End Sub

Sub sort_(k As Long)
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = Worksheets("Result")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With sht.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=sht.Range("B2:B" & k + 1), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                        Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange sht.Range("A2:B" & k + 1)
        .Header = xlGuess: .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin: .Apply
    End With

    Set sht = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```